# Using listIterator to add objects alphabetically to a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, alphabetical, listiterator

I am attempting to add Strings to a linked list in alphabetical order. Everything is working alright except when I call the add() method on my iterator object, it adds the String *after* the current iterator position instead of before, thus messing up my alphabetical order.

Is there a way to have it add the object right before the current position of the iterator?

Thanks in advance,
Tyler

p.s. It seems like other's on stack overflow were having the complete opposite problem, very strange.

```
 //addElement method, adds string to the linked list in alphabetical order
 public void addElement(Object obj)
 {
   String inString = (String) obj;
   iter = listIterator();
   Node newNode = new Node();
   newNode.data = obj;

   if (first != null)
   {
       int checker = 0;
       while (iter.hasNext()==true && checker == 0)
       {
           String testString = (String) iter.next();
           int i = inString.compareTo(testString);
           if (i <= 0)
           {
               iter.add((Object) inString);
               checker++;
           }

       } 

       if (checker == 0)
           iter.add((Object) inString);

   }

   else
   {
       //iter.add((Object) inString);
       addFirst((Object) inString);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very inefficient way to sort. Try using the sort function instead. If you have to do insertion, then don't use the list iterator - keep the index of where you're looking at and use the `add(index, value)` version of add - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add(int,%20E)

You could also use `previousIndex()` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previousIndex() on the iterator to find the index to insert at for insertion before. This is unlikely to make you happy.